# Inconsistent behavior: GCI / -Include

Tags: powershell

I'm working on an automated cleanup script that uses `Get-ChildItem` pretty liberally.  I filter the contents to clean from an XML configuration with the `-Include` flag since it takes a string array while `-Filter` does not.  Here's the offending block in question:

```
Function CleanFolders
{
  Write-Log 'Cleaning Folders..' status

  ForEach ($Folder in $Config.OS.$Build.Folders.Folder)
  {
    If (Test-Path $Folder.Name)
    {
      Try {
        GCI $Folder.Name -Include $Folder.Include -Recurse -Force |
          Where { ($_.Length -gt ([Int]$Folder.Threshold * 1MB)) -and
                  ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-[Int]$Folder.Expiration)) } |
          Sort $_.IsPSContainer -Descending |
          % {
            Try {
              Write-Log "Deleting $($_.FullName)"
              Remove-Item "$($_.FullName)" -Force
            } Catch {
              Write-Log 'Unable to delete item' error
              Write-Log "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] - $($_.Exception.Message)" error
            }
          }
      } Catch { Write-Log "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] - $($_.Exception.Message)" error }
    } Else { Write-Log "$($Folder.Name) does not exist" error }
  }
}
```

The script is run from a scheduled task as SYSTEM and for some reason, is not returning results from the `-Include` flag that are not just a wildcard `*`.  Are there known issues with `-Include`?  This operation runs properly when run as a user account with admin privileges.

Comment: @briantist That doesn't address my problem.  It works when run as my admin account, but not as a scheduled SYSTEM account.

Comment: Why, then, would you think the problem is with `-Include` if the only difference is the credentials you're running under? Normally, `SYSTEM` should have access to all files, but it is of course possible to remove access from it, or specifically deny it access. Verify that the script works when running as `SYSTEM` with [`psexec -s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). If that works, something is going wrong with launching the script.

Comment: Should `GCI $Folder.Name` be `GCI $Folder.FullName`?  Name is typically just the filename, and you'd want the full path.  If default path for your account and SYSTEM is different (likely) then you'd see different behavior.  Generally, however, I would avoid the `-Include` parameter entirely.  It's flaky.  I'd favor the `-Filter` parameter for wildcards, and `Where-Object` for anything more complex.  I also wonder if you've got a scope problem because neither `$Config` nor `$Build` appear to be defined nor global/script scoped variables in your code.

Comment: @BaconBits I had a coworker assist me with it.  It turns out the XML being loaded wasn't making the string an array, but a single string with commas which `-Include` was trying to take literally.  Also `$Folder.Name` was referring to the XML object, not the actual folder.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 But that doesn't explain why the same code worked when you ran it?  In any event, you should add your answer and mark the question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with my script was my method of getting the xml into a variable.  I was using `Get-Content` which did not preserve any formatting or type information, rather than `Import-CliXml`.  This was causing the `Get-ChildItem -Include` arguments to be entered as a single string rather than a string array (since they were comma-separated in the xml).

My resolution around this was creating an object with defined types (such as the expected string array (`String[]`) rather than worrying about creating/exporting/importing an xml file.

```
$global:Config = @{
  OS = @{
    Workstation = @{
      Folders = @( @{ Name=..;Include=..;Expiration=..;Threshold=..;} );
    };
  };
};
```